# org-babel results with accented characters

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, character-encoding

I have a problem with the output of org-babel code blocks when this output contains accented characters. For example, if I execute this code block:

```
#+name: test_accented
#+begin_src python :results output
print("éèà")
#+end_src
```

the result is:

```
#+RESULTS: test_accented
: Ã©Ã¨Ã
```

My config relating to encoding is:

```
;; utf-8 ;; 
(setq locale-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8)
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

I use emacs 25.2.2, org-mode 9.2.3 and python 3.6.7. I also tried with another language (ruby) and the result is the same.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem but you could check a couple of things: 1) Does your buffer use UTF8 encoding? Check the left side of the mode line for a "U" indicator. 2) Is your `org-babel-python-command` set to `python3`? I got errors with python2.

Comment: @NickD Thanks for your help; the buffer uses UTF8 encoding ( more specifically utf-8-unix) and I have no problem with accented characters outside the results blocks. The problems seems to occur when the result is produced. The variable `org-babel-python-command` is well set to `python3`.

Comment: @NickD I finally solved the problem by modifying in emacs: Option > Multilingual Environment > Set Language Environnement > UTF-8 and it work (I do not understand exactly why)

Comment: OK - glad you worked it out. It may be that one of the buffers that `org-babel` uses ended up with the wrong encoding.

Comment: @Lgen In [Aquamacs](https://aquamacs.org) using `Options > Language > Set Language Environment > UTF-8` worked for me. (Using "org-babel" with Raku over Cyrillic and Hiragana/Kanji inputs.) I also would like to know why it did not work "right-away."